# How to name an input in order to be an array as a Dynamic form and then sum those values?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have a dynamic form with JavaScript:

```
row.insertCell(4).innerHTML= '<input type="text" name="precioUniArr[]" value = "'+precioUnitario+'">'
```

Is there a way to get the values of all the `precioUniArr[]` inputs with JavaScript in order to make a sum and have a total?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: So do you mean there would be multiple input names like:  name="precioUniArr[0]", name="precioUniArr[1]", name="precioUniArr[2]" etc?  And you want to get the values from each and put them in an array?

Answer (score 3):

You use `document.getElementsByName("precioUniArr[]")`. This returns a `NodeList`, which is an array-like object that you can loop over to get all the values.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("precioUniArr[]");
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    var value = parseFloat(inputs[i].value);
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        total += value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be trying Java or C methods to get this information. JavaScript works a little bit differently, as the input field always, no matter what, returns a string of text.

Try giving the array a simple ID of `precioUniArr`.

When you need to grab the data inside, assuming it's a comma-separated list for input, try this code (it grabs the string of input and splits it into an array by each comma):

```
inputArray = document.getElementById('precioUniArr').value.split(',');
```

This will store an array formed by a comma-separated string as the array `inputArray`. If it's a space-separated list, just replace the comma in the code with a space.

Comment: I think he's building a table dynamically with multiple inputs. You can't repeat the same ID for each of them.

Comment: Oh, I thought that he was having users enter a list of items into one input field.

Comment: Exactly, Im building a table dynamically.